# moving trig function from the exponent?

Tags: trigonometry, exponentiation

Is there a form of $e^{\sin(x)}$ that does not have trig functions in the exponent?  I've seen the "Euler Identity" form and looked into series expansions.  (thanks for the answers -- sorry I didn't give background earlier.)  I'm curious if there was something computationally faster than sin() then exp().

Comment: It is possible to rewrite it without using the symbol $\sin$ (see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/705131/55235)), but by its very nature $\sin$ will always be there, whether you see it or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this
$$
e^{\sin(x)} = e^{\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})}
$$
But I doubt that's what you're looking for.  A common trick in situations like this is to use the taylor series.  So you could try
$$
e^{\sin(x)} = e^{x-x^3/6 + x^5/120 - \cdots}
$$
or
$$
e^{\sin(x)} = 1 + \sin(x) + \sin^2(x)/2 + \sin^{3}(x)/6 + \cdots
$$